# Group records by last 6 weeks, find most recent record based on date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help to create a sql query to get the most recent serial record after sorting based on date in decending, for a timeframe of previous 6 weeks.
I was able to do this for one month without any issues. But am not able to think of an approach to do this for previous six weeks. I read that range between preceding and current row can be used to achieve this but i had no success.

This is a sample data:

Source : Random data between 21-Feb-20 and 3-Apr-20 (previous six weeks from current day)

```
Serial  Repair_dt
1       3-Apr-20
1       12-Mar-20
2       12-Mar-20
3       12-Mar-20
4       28-Feb-20
4       1-Mar-20
4       2-Apr-20
4       3-Apr-20
5       23-Feb-20
5       19-Mar-20
6       1-Mar-20
```

Rank to find recent record based on date desc, grouped by serial:

```
Serial  Repair_dt   rank
1       3-Apr-20    1
1       12-Mar-20   2
2       12-Mar-20   1
3       12-Mar-20   1
4       2-Apr-20    1
4       2-Apr-20    2
4       1-Mar-20    3
4       28-Feb-20   4
5       19-Mar-20   1
5       23-Feb-20   2
6       1-Mar-20    1
```

Final Output :

```
Serial  Repair_dt   rank
1       3-Apr-20    1
2       12-Mar-20   1
3       12-Mar-20   1
4       2-Apr-20    1
5       19-Mar-20   1
6       1-Mar-20    1
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.
Kav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a rank for this.  Aggregation works for the data you have described:

```
select serial, max(repair_dt) as repair_dt
from t
where repair_dt > sysdate - interval '42' day
group by serial;
```

If you want the entire row, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.repair_dt = (select max(t2.repair_dt)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.serial = t.serial and
                           t2.repair_dt > sysdate - interval '42' day
                    );
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by serial order by repair_dt desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where t2.repair_dt > sysdate - interval '42' day
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But the above query is for last 6 months right ? I wanted to do this for the previous 6 weeks. I did try replacing add_months(sysdate, -6) with trunc(sysdate) - (6*7) but i get null records.

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy . . . I fixed it.

Comment: I just did a select sysdate - interval '6' week from dual; and got a bunch of errors : `ORA-30089: missing or invalid <datetime field>
30089. 00000 -  "missing or invalid <datetime field>"
*Cause:    A <datetime field> (YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND) is
           expected but not found, or a <datetime field> specified the
           <end field> in an <interval qualifier> is more significant
           than its <start field>.`

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy . . . I had no idea that Oracle doesn't support `week` (most databases do).  In any case, this works:  `select sysdate - interval '42' day from dual`.

Comment: Note that it's possible to get multiple rows if it duplicate repair_dt values are possible.

Comment: @eaolson can you explain a little more please ? Woudn't max(repair_dt) return only one value ? Are you talking about the second query , where entire row is selected ?

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy . . . That would be directed at the second query.  The alternative is to use `row_number()`.  The first query cannot return duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, i got it. I was just wondering how row_number() can be used here. Can you possibly give me a small example ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff perfect! what exactly i was looking for. Appreciate all the help !